# How do I figure out what dimensional space vectors that are perpendicular to another specified vector lie on?

Tags: linear-algebra

a) Describe every vector $\overrightarrow { w } ={ (w }_{ 1 },{ w }_{ 2 })$ that is perpendicular to $\overrightarrow { v } =(2,-1)$

b) The vectors that are perpendicular to $\overrightarrow{V} = (1,1,1)$ lie on a ____.

c) The vectors that are perpendicular to $(1,1,1)$ and $(1,2,3)$ lie on a ____.

Steps I took:

For part a, I realized that in order to find the perpendicular vectors I need the dot product of $\overrightarrow{v}$ and $\overrightarrow{w}$ to be equal to $0$. This will show that they are perpendicular. 
So,

$$\left[ \begin{matrix} 2 \\ -1 \end{matrix} \right] \cdot \left[ \begin{matrix} { w }_{ 1 } \\ { w }_{ 2 } \end{matrix} \right] =0\quad \Rightarrow \quad \overrightarrow { w } =\left[ \begin{matrix} c \\ 2c \end{matrix} \right] $$

Now parts b and c have me really confused. I don't know what kind of dimensional space that the vectors perpendicular to $\overrightarrow{V} = (1,1,1)$ will lie on. I don't even know how to properly reason through it.

Hints only, please. The actual solution does me no good.

Comment: Given a generic $(x,y,z)$, consider the dot product $(x,y,z) \cdot (1,1,1) = x + y + z$. To be perpendicular, we need a zero dot product. So you have one linear equation and $3$ unknowns, what would you expect te dimension to be?

Comment: So $x+y+z = 0$? I can't seem to understand how I would figure out the dimensions from that piece of information.

Answer (score 1):

If you're solving $x+y+z = 0$, you've got one equation with three unknowns. You should be thinking that you'll have at least $3 - 1$ free variables/degrees of freedom (variables give you freedom, equations typically take them away).

More precisely, we must have that $z = -x - y$, and... that's our only obligation! We have two free variables so we'll have a plane ($2$-dimensional subspace) of perpendicular vectors.

If we wanted to, we could write our generic vector perpendicular to $(1,1,1)$ as

$$\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ -x -y \end{bmatrix} = x\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} + y\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix},$$

and produce a basis (consisting of two vectors) that span the $2$-dimensional subspace perpendicular to $(1,1,1)$.

Hopefully you've got some intuition about the third part, by now -- you'll have three variables still, but now two equations (since two dot products have to be $0$).

Comment: I have to catch a flight right now. I will look into your explanation in a couple of hours. I imagine that I will have follow up questions. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Now for the third part, do I just have two equations as such:

$$\left[ \begin{matrix} u \\ v \\ w \end{matrix} \right] \cdot \left[ \begin{matrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{matrix} \right] =0\quad and\quad \left[ \begin{matrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{matrix} \right] =\left[ 1\\ 2\\ 3 \right] \Rightarrow u+v+w=0\quad and\quad x+y+z=0$$ ?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer Yeah, if $\begin{bmatrix}x & y & z\end{bmatrix}^T$ is perpendicular to both $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}^T$ and $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 3\end{bmatrix}^T$, then from both dot products being $0$ you'll get the equations $x + y + z = 0$ and $x + 2y + 3z = 0$. You'll have one free variable (you can solve for two of the variables in terms of the third), and you can write the subspace as the span of a single vector (where single vectors span lines).

Comment: So I guess maybe I should say "Use the same vector of variables for both dot products" since it's got to be perpendicular to both.

Comment: I'm having trouble turning those two equations into a single vector. Do I treat it a a system of equations? $x+y+z=0\quad and\quad x+2y+3z=0$ $\Rightarrow y+2x=0\Rightarrow y=-2z$ I don't know whether my reasoning is correct and where to go from here.